# When I use mybatis cursor and druid , I got an exception "java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed"

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, druid

Why use ResultSet.close in DefaultCursor.Iterator.hasNext, when I use mybatis cursor and druid, I got an exception "java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed".
Spring boot version：2.3.2.RELEASE
com.alibaba:druid-spring-boot-starter:1.2.5
org.mybatis:mybatis:3.5.6
mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18
[DefaultCursor](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/c9803a9bfbb9ee927b1d97a4375ceadf278b9531/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/cursor/defaults/DefaultCursor.java)
at method: fetchNextObjectFromDatabase

```java
 // No more object or limit reached
    if (!objectWrapperResultHandler.fetched || getReadItemsCount() == rowBounds.getOffset() + rowBounds.getLimit()) {
      close();
      status = CursorStatus.CONSUMED;
    }
```

**I want to close it manually by myself?How to do it?**
Below is the code I use.
DriverService.java

```java
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void streamDriver(EnterpriseDTO dto) {
        Cursor<Driver> cursor = baseMapper.findNeedDriver(dto.getEnterpriseId());
        Iterator<Driver> iterator = cursor.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Driver driver = iterator.next();
                
            log.info(driver.getDriverName());
        }
```

BaseMapper.java(interface)

```java
    @Select("select * from t_driver t where t.enterprise_id = #{enterpriseId} and t.deleted = 0")
    Cursor<Driver> findNeedDriver(@Param("enterpriseId") Long enterpriseId);
```

I found a [Similar issue on github](https://github.com/alibaba/druid/issues/3641)
But the problem is not solved.
**I want to resolve this exception, what should I do?**

Comment: All opened cursors are automatically closed when the transaction ends. It seems the transaction ended already and you are trying to close the cursor. There's no need for you do do that. Just verify the transaction demarcation (`@Transactional`) is annotating the right methods.

Comment: As your code shows the cursor will only live inside the method `streamDriver()`, since this is the method annotated with `@Transactional`.

Comment: @np7sky Please explain what do you want to achieve (i.e. what do you want to do if the cursor is not closed automatically). Regarding the linked issue, Druid should not call `setFetchSize()` if the statement is closed, I think.

Comment: @ave I need to resolve this exception. I want to use Druid's monitoring and statistics capabilities,  if the cursor is not closed automatically, spring transactional whill call druid to close statement. In my limited experience with Druid, Druid use filter pattern to implement monitoring and statistics functions. The most fundamental reason is that I need to query a lot of data and I need to control memory usage.   mybait cursor which  seems it's a promising solution, Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @np7sky Well, as I explained, Druid should not call `setFetchSize()` if the statement is closed. Hope that issue gets fixed soon. 